# Unable to start MongoDB 3.0.9,3.1.9,3.2.0,3.2.1 after installation on Windows 2012

Tags: mongodb

Unable to start MongoDB 3.0.9,3.1.9,3.2.0,3.2.1 after installation on Windows 2012 R2 after installation. Continually receive APPCRASH errors. MSVCR120.dll c000001d.

Builds 2.7.9 and 3.0.0 do not experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by installing the 64 bit (or 32 bit) version of  the Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013. It can be downloaded from Microsoft: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was done. Both 64 bit & 32 bit were tried, but none of the above mentioned builds will start.

Comment: Are you using Virtual Machines ?

Comment: Yes. It's running on KVM.